# How to detect NetStream is stopped its publishing of data?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, netstream

My application is sending live video to AMS so for that I used `Netstream.attachCamera(camera)` I can able to send live video through `NetStream.publish("myStreamingURL', "live");` I stopped netsteaming by using `NetStream.close()` method, now my problem is I want to stop my live video If NetStream has stopped its publishing streaming. How can I detect NetStream is stopped its publishing of data?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a listener for `NetStatusEvent` and check within the listener for `event.info.code`.

[Complete List of NetStatusEvent-Codes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html)